# Master-Master replication consequences

Tags: ravendb

I'm migrating my RavenDb database to `RavenHq` and trying to setup replication for the first time. I'm considering to have a Master-Master replication with `Failover` equal to `AllowReadsFromSecondariesAndWritesToSecondaries`. What kind of behaviour will change in this case in comparison to single server scenario.

As I understand RavenDb will write to Master and read from Master (so edit-list scenario should not be a problem) until failover happens. So my only concern should be resolve failover-related conflicts (that are pretty unlikely to happen). Or should I take anything else into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Note that conflicts can be handled automatically by the server by selecting the appropriate strategy